# ImportError: undefined symbol: _PyUnicodeUCS4_IsWhitespace

Tags: python, numpy

I am a python beginner and I would like some help with this. I am using Ubuntu and I had installed python using Anaconda, but then I tried to install it again using pip and now when I'm trying to run my code, at `import numpy as np`, I see this error

`ImportError: /home/dev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: _PyUnicodeUCS4_IsWhitespace`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error. If you google for it, you will find lot's of similar issues. The problem can happen when you have multiple Python versions. In my case, I had the Ubuntu 16.04 Python 2.7 via `/usr/bin/python` and another Python 2.7 via Linuxbrew. `type python` gave me `/u/zeyer/.linuxbrew/bin/python2`, i.e. the Linuxbrew one. `type pip2.7` gave me `/u/zeyer/.local/bin/pip2.7`, and looking into that file, it had the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python`, i.e. it was using the Ubuntu Python.

So, there are various solutions. You could just edit the `pip2.7` file and change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`. Or reinstall pip in some way.

In my case, I found that the Python 2.7 via Linuxbrew was incompatible to a few packages I needed (e.g. Tensorflow), so I unlinked it and use only the Ubuntu 16.04 Python 2.7 now.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall numpy:

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

And reinstall numpy:

```
pip install numpy
```

Another thing you can do is run it on a virtual environment:

```
virtualenv myproject
cd myproject
source bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

Comment: I uninstalled it successfully and at `pip install numpy` I got this message : `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. I tried  `sudo pip install numpy`  and I saw this `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. When I run the code now I see this error **ImportError: No module named numpy**

Comment: Seems like  to be a mismatch of Python and Numpy compile settings.Possibly a conflict.Try running it on a virtual enviroment.Let me add that to my answer.

Comment: Also on `python --version` I see this `Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)`. Don't know if that helps

Comment: I'm trying to install virtualenv and i get this message on terminal **E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).** Then after running `apt-get -f install` I get this `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?`

Comment: Did you run it as administrator? sudo?

Comment: Yes i run `sudo apt-get install virtualenv`